# python tensorflow: nan loss using softmax_cross_entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use the pretrained parameter to my vgg net(except last three layers). And I only train the last three layers of my vgg net.

I noticed that the preprocess of image of vgg net should minus the mean value of RGB. However, it seems needn't to convert the pixels value to [-1,1].

I use softmax_cross_entropy to get my loss. The logit is the last output of vgg net. The last layer of vgg is conv(actually fc). And the label is one hot label.

I've tried a lot of configure of the learning rate, eg 0.1 0.03 0.01 0.003 0.001. However, the first three learning rate lead to the nan loss. The last two configurations lead to unstable loss. Should I still decrease the learning rate? I noticed that for many examples values such as 0.1 or 0.01 are good to go.
   Please help me. Here's my code.

```
_R_MEAN = 123.68
_G_MEAN = 116.78
_B_MEAN = 103.94
...
samples_all, labels_all = getsamples()
...
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(imagecontent, channels=3)
image=tf.image.resize_images(image, [240, 320])
channels = tf.split(2, 3, image)
channels[0] -= _R_MEAN
channels[1] -= _G_MEAN
channels[2] -= _B_MEAN
image=tf.concat(2, channels)
...
images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], 4, 2, 32)
net, end = vgg16Net(images, num_classes = 101, is_training=True)
...
losses.softmax_cross_entropy(net, labels)
total_loss = losses.get_total_loss()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(total_loss, var_list=train_var)
...
```

Comment: Your code is a mess, could you see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?